# Many to many relation in Cosmos DB + EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

### Preamble

Hi there! Yet another question from a Cosmos DB newbie:
How to effectively implement many-to-many relation in Cosmos DB using Entity Framework Core?

Docs already read with no luck (popular answers for similar questions on SO):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/modeling-data
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/data-modeling-and-partitioning-for-relational-workloads/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/planetary-docs-sample

## Task

I develop a simple app for doctors for quick screening of a patient. It has just three entities:

- Disease - something we have to identify
- Symptom - observable sign of some potential disease
- Tag - just a label for quick data organization

They all have many-to-many relation to each other. Simple schema is shown on the picture below. Looks naively easy.

[image: Entities and relations]

## Problem

The problem is that the main feature of the app is a quick filtering by any of these criteria. In real datasets entities are about *tens* x *tens* x *tens* times connected with each other and usage of traditional SQL expected to hang the server under the load. Three intermediate tables with two indexes on each column and so on...

## Possible solution

And here a shiny NoSQL should appear on the scene to save us - Azure Cosmos DB in my case.

### Expected solution

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/modeling-data#how-do-i-model-many-to-many-relationships) I want to store the data in the next way (embed array of references):

```
Diseases:
{"id": "d1", "name": "Covid-19", "symptoms": ["s1", "s3"], "tags": ["t1"]}
{"id": "d2", "name": "Flu", "symptoms": ["s1", "s2"], "tags": ["t1", "t2"]}

Symptoms:
{"id": "s1", "name": "High temperature", "diseases": ["d1", "d2"], "tags": ["t1", "t2"]}
{"id": "s2", "name": "Runny nose", "diseases": ["d1"], "tags": ["t1", "t2"]}
{"id": "s3", "name": "Cough", "diseases": ["d2"], "tags": ["t1", "t2"]}

Tags:
{"id": "t1", "name": "Virus", "diseases": ["d1", "d2"], "symptoms": ["s1", "s2", "s3"]}
{"id": "t2", "name": "Infection", "diseases": ["d1"], "symptoms": ["s1", "s2", "s3"]}
```

With such data organization I expect to be able find any relation between entities and make filtering lightning fast.

### Assumptions

I expect that Cosmos DB:

- updates reference lists automatically when they're changed without need of reacting to `Change Feed` events
- keep references consistent
- automatically makes `JOIN`s (or any NoSQL equivalent) when it is requested and returns references as a collection of actual entities
- allows to filter data by partial match in references - find all diseases with any/all symptoms we observe

## Implementation

As mentioned above I use Cosmos DB with SQL API and Entity Framework Core code first with very dummy classes like:

```
public class Disease
{
    public string Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Symptom> Symptoms { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

### Actual result

Using them I can successfully create main entities with relations between them but cannot read them with nested collections. As querying doesn't work correctly:

- I cannot edit/remove links between entities
- Repeated (blind) reference add throws a duplication exception

All entities:

- are stored in the same (default) container
- use default `discriminator`
- have no `__partitionKey` defined. I tried to use `Id` but it still it is always `null` for some reason and fails on insert
- intermediate entities created automatically with `discriminator`, no `__partitionKey` and two `FK`s
- Entity Framework`s `.Include(d => d.Symptoms)` throws `InvalidOperationException: Including navigation 'SkipNavigation: Disease.Symptoms (ICollection<Symptom>) CollectionSymptom Inverse: Diseases' is not supported as the navigation is not embedded in same resource.`

How it looks like in Emulator
[image: Entities created]

As a result I have BrokenSQL storage which is neither SQL nor NoSQL =(

### Configuration approaches

I tried next approaches:

- Implicit relations definition - just properties
- Explicit relations definition - using `DbContext.OnModelCreating()`

  - `dm.Entry<Disease>().HasMany(d => d.Symptoms).WithMany(s => s.Diseases)` - works the same way as just properties
  - `dm.Entry<Disease>().HasOwn(d => d.Symptoms).HasOwn(s => s.Diseases)` - doesn't work as incorrect data model (obviously)

## Questions

- Is NoSQL a good approach to solve the problem or should I go back to relational DB?
- Is Cosmos DB a suitable tool for this?

  - Doesn't `SQL API` affect the result?
- Is Entity Framework Core is good choice to interact with Cosmos DB?
- If all answers are positive - how could I fix the behavior of my app?

  - Might it be related to missing `__partitionKey`? If yes - how could I fix that?
  - Any useful links out there?

Comment: As I see,  Cosmos DB do not support Cross-item and cross-container joins.  Also consider to review NewSql, for example [Singlestore](https://www.singlestore.com) it has MySql interface and should work with EF Core. They scales horizontally and has very fast JOINs.

Comment: This really is far too broad, as you're asking a *lot* of questions. Your first question is purely opinion-based (and "NoSQL" isn't a real thing - it's an umbrella term for any non-relational database). your second question is also opinion-based (whether it's suitable to use) - but I don't understand your comment about SQL API.

Comment: Finally: please note that the SQL API does not mean you're working with a relational databases - there are no references being updated between documents (unless entity framework is taking an active role in updating things for you)

Answer (score 3):

Lots to unpack here.

Let's start with your assumptions:

- *updates reference lists automatically when they're changed without need of reacting to Change Feed events* as well as *keep references consistent*

  - This is incorrect. Changes to master data such as tags or symptoms (which I assume as stored in a different container), materialized in your diseases container do not get updated in the container with the master data, or in the container where they are materialized, when either of these are changed. There is no magic bullet or hidden hand here keeping data in sync. Change feed is the mechanism by which you maintain referential integrity for data between containers.
- *automatically makes JOINs (or any NoSQL equivalent) when it is requested and returns references as a collection of actual entities*

  - I'm not sure what you mean here but there are no automatic joins. To be clear, joins can only be made between a document and data stored as a child object or array within it. See [SQL Query Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-join) for more details.
- *allows to filter data by partial match in references - find all diseases with any/all symptoms we observe*

  - There is no partial match on arrays in Cosmos DB. You can find instances of an object within an array by using [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-array-contains). Partial string matching can be done with [REGEXMATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-regexmatch)

WRT your actual results:

- *I cannot edit/remove links between entities*
- *Repeated (blind) reference add throws a duplication exception*

  I'm not sure what either of these means.
- *All entities are stored in the same (default) container*

  - I assume that symptoms are shared between diseases. Where are you storing the master data for symptoms? Same for Tags. These normally would be stored in a different container using a "type" property as a discriminator for the different entity types, then denormalized into this container you have now.
- *have no __partitionKey defined. I tried to use Id but it still it is always null for some reason and fails on insert.*

  - If you're requirement is to make things, "lightning fast" you need to figure out a partition key such that the queries run with the highest concurrency are served by a container with a partition key that will answer queries hitting a single (or small bounded number of) logical partition(s). If you query by disease most of the time, then use `id` if that is the value for the disease itself. If you query by symptoms, then querying this container you have will be cross partition and will not scale. But if querying by symptoms is a frequent query, I suggest you model your data in such a way that you can find all the diseases that have that symptom in a symptoms container that has diseases as an array within it. If you search by tags all the time, then model and partition your data that way, etc.
- *entity framework*

  - EF appears to be the source of some of your problems as you are accepting defaults that later cause problems for you. It's probably fine after you figure out your partitioning strategy and data model to best answer your queries but at this stage it seems like it's not helpful. Or at least use the Portal to test your queries first to ensure your partition strategy is correct, then implement with it when you've sorted out your design issues.

Cosmos DB is fine for workloads like this. But there are no magic bullets. You need to model and partition your data such that it can serve the queries you are designing for. Concepts like maintaining referential integrity between master and transactional data are done with change feed.

You've pointed to some of the documentation on this. I also recommend watching this talk on modeling and partitioning. There is also a GitHub repo at the end of the talk with a TON of samples you can clone and view for yourself that cover all of these design decisions you are trying to make. [Data modeling and partitioning in Azure Cosmos DB: What every relational database user needs to know](https://youtu.be/utdxvAhIlcY)